# PHP image generation error

Tags: php, php-gd

I was trying to run an example given in a book that produces a PNG image on the page:

```
<?php
//set up image
$height = 200;
$width = 200;

$im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

//draw on image
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $blue);
imageline($im, 0, 0, $width, $height, $white);
imagestring($im, 4, 50, 150, 'Sales', $white);

//output image
Header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);

//clean up
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

The problem is that when I run it, all I get is a broken image icon. Firefox additionally tells me that the image can't be displayed because it contains error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is working perfectly. See [**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yvm5kQ).

Comment: Same here, nothing wrong with this (FF 28.0). Are you sure you're running THAT code?

Comment: Have you go error reporting on? `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true)`

Comment: Have you installed php5-gd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your content type is wrong. You're making a JPG but telling the browser it is a PNG:

```
Header('Content-type: image/png');
imagejpeg($im);
```

should be

```
Header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
```

**edit**

This question was edited to correct this. This edit solves the problem: http://codepad.viper-7.com/FTW3g0

Comment: Their **original** code had the error I show above. They since edited their question to correct this. I left my answer and then posted the link demonstrating that it now works.

Comment: The first part of my answer. They originally had `imagejpeg($im);` instead of `imagepng($im);`.

Comment: But you have `Header('Content-type: image/png');
imagejpeg($im);` `png` + `imagejpeg` and vice-versa. Shouldn't that be  `Header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);` and `Header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);`?

Comment: Now that's a horse of a different color! That was an unintended mistake on my part. Corrected.

Comment: *Ah*, there we go (Et voilà) ;-) Plus uno.

Comment: This is probably a sign that I need to stop braining for the day to go to bed.

Comment: These darn things have a way to play tricks on our eyes for sure.

Comment: I suspect OP has a space before `<?php` which threw me an error and showed code instead of an image.

Comment: Assuming the code above is really what they are using then that's the only thing it can be. At least they know they have working code.

Comment: Which is why I voted to close.

Comment: @JakeGould I tried with both `header('Content-Type: image/png');` and `Header('Content-type: image/png');` and even mixed case `HeadEr('Content-tYpE: image/png');` and it worked fine. FF 28.0

Comment: @JohnConde Thank you! I had to fiddle around a little but your solution showed me the right direction. It looks like I'm able to render jpeg but not png. Changing to `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg')` and `imagejpeg($im)` worked for me. Any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to run this in PHP 5.4.10 without issue.  And viewable as a PNG:

[image]

What version of PHP are you using? Are you sure the GD library is installed?  Open up a PHP file & place this [`phpinfo`](https://www.php.net/phpinfo) command at the top of it to see if GD is loaded:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

That said, I did notice an odd error in PHP 5.2.17 which I can switch to in my MAMP setup: Even if I have the command `die();` after your code, the page bombs out. Something is different in the PHP parser between PHP 5.4.10 and PHP 5.2.17 it seems. But that is just me. Unclear what your setup is like.

**EDIT** I think I figured out the issue. Some browsers are case sensitive to headers.  So change this:

```
//output image
Header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
```

To this:

```
//output image
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
```

Note the capital `T` in `Content-Type` in my edit.  Try that out.

Comment: I tried running his code and got the same issue as him: http://www.apptic.me/sample/test.php

Comment: And here is the phpinfo() output: http://www.apptic.me/sample/info.php

Comment: You might have loaded the link before I had a chance to fix it, sorry. Fixed now.

Comment: @Neel That's most likely because your file is either saved as UTF-8 with BOM or there's a space before the opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: Hmm, there is no space. Shouldn't the save format not matter since it's just PHP outputting the contents? I'm saving using UTF-8, not sure if BOM.